# Symfony2 Access Created Date Inside Controller

Tags: php, json, symfony

I need to be able to access the created date inside the controller because I need to send it back in a JSON response, having issues though.

This works, but the JSON response dies because the print_r prints the object inside the controller:

```
 print_r($validateListing[0]->getCreated());
 $date = $validateListing[0]->getCreated()->date;
 $createdDate = date("m/d/Y", strtotime($date));
```

This Doesn't, and this is the one I need to use so that I can attach the formatted date inside the response.

```
 $date = $validateListing[0]->getCreated()->date;
 $createdDate = date("m/d/Y", strtotime($date));
```

When I remove the print_r(), this fails... What can I do to make this work?

This is the error that I get:

```
 Notice: Undefined property: DateTime::$date in ...
```

Thanks!

Comment: Found the answer and posted it below.

Answer (score 0):

$date = $validateListing[0]->getCreated()->format('r');
$createdDate = date("m/d/Y", strtotime($date));

There is no ->date attribute in the DateTime object, which is why PHP's complaining about $validateListing[0]->getCreated()->date.

Answer (score 0):

The returned value for get is `DateTime` so you need to convert the format as below

```
$createdDate = $validateListing[0]->getCreated()->format('m/d/Y');
```